# Rcpp - How do I use the source code from an R package in C++?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to write a program in C++ which uses several functions from the [infotheo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/infotheo/infotheo.pdf) R package.

I downloaded the source files for the package and copied over the .cpp files I need. For example,

```
#include "infotheo.h"

SEXP entropyR (SEXP Rdata, SEXP Rnrows, SEXP Rncols, SEXP Rchoice)
{
      const int *data;
      const int *nrows, *ncols, *choice;
         SEXP res;
         PROTECT(Rdata = AS_INTEGER(Rdata));
         PROTECT(Rnrows= AS_INTEGER(Rnrows));
         PROTECT(Rncols= AS_INTEGER(Rncols));
     PROTECT(Rchoice= AS_INTEGER(Rchoice));
         data = INTEGER_POINTER(Rdata);
         nrows= INTEGER_POINTER(Rnrows);
         ncols= INTEGER_POINTER(Rncols);   
     choice= INTEGER_POINTER(Rchoice);    
         PROTECT(res = NEW_NUMERIC(1));
         bool *sel = new bool[*ncols];
         for( int i=0; i<*ncols; ++i )
            sel[i] = true;
         REAL(res)[0] = entropy(data, *nrows, *ncols, *choice, sel);
         UNPROTECT(5);
      return res;
}
```

Clearly this uses the SEXP class from the Rcpp package. My program will not use R at all. My question is: **Is the best way to do this to rewrite the code replacing SEXP types with explicit C++ data structures?**

[This](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-extending.pdf) tutorial shows that Rcpp::as can essentially convert the SEXP class into another. **But does this mean I would again have to replace the SEXP variables with Foo(SEXP) throughout? Or should I convert my numeric array to a SEXP, and continue with the infotheo classes as is?**

Comment: You _really_, _really_, _really_ need to [read the R Internals manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) before posting this type of question.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I've now read some more of the manual but I'm still unsure about how to progress. Is there a specific section you think is helpful to the question?

Comment: Do you now know what a `SEXP` is/isn't? If so, you rly don't need to post this question anymore. If not, did you read any of the other [‘manuals](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) including [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html)? But, if persistence fails, the short answer is to perhaps look at the `X` in the right-hand `X_POINTER` uses and use that type for the variables and not worry about the garbage collection `PROTECT`ing.

Comment: And your _"uses the `SEXP` class from the Rcpp package"_ is plain wrong.  Rcpp gives you C++ alternatives to `SEXP`; the `SEXP` comes from R and @hrbrmstr is correct.

Comment: Also the function you listed just does the interfacing (which Rcpp would make minimal). You are more interested in `entropy(data, *nrows, *ncols, *choice, sel);`.